# Pulling data from multiple columns if a name matches from another list

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016

So i'm trying to make a formula that looks at the server names which i provide in a separate sheet and see if that name is in a column of the other sheet and extract the specific columns which i tell it to into another sheet.

For example i would provide all the server names that i want to pull from the full report

```
Names that need to be pulled
Server1
Server3
Server4
```

It looks in the name column for the names that need to be pulled and pulls all the columns which i specify for it to pull onto the other sheet

```
Type    Name    Lead    Start Date  End Date    Confirmation
AIX    server1  Bob     23/02/2019  24/02/2019  Success
Java   server2  steve   24/02/2019  25/02/2019  Success
java   server3  steve   25/02/2019  26/02/2019  Not Booked
AIX    server4  bob     26/02/2019  27/02/2019  Booked
```

This then results in only the rows with servers 1 3 and 4 to be extracted to the other sheet aswell as the specific columns only to get pulled onto the other sheet.

```
Type    Name    Lead    Start Date  End Date
AIX    server1  Bob     23/02/2019  24/02/2019
java   server3  steve   25/02/2019  26/02/2019
AIX    server4  bob     26/02/2019  27/02/2019
```

Is this possible, what would be the best way to go about this?

Apologies if this is in the wrong place to post this any help is appreciated.

Comment: look into [VLOOKUP](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/VLOOKUP-function-0BBC8083-26FE-4963-8AB8-93A18AD188A1)

Comment: This is what Advanced Filter is for.

Comment: Can there be multiple instances of a given server in the searched data sheet? (i.e. the second table shown in the question has servers 1-4, could there be a fifth row with a second server1?) Since one of the values you return is left of the search value, use [INDEX/MATCH](https://www.excel-university.com/how-to-return-a-value-left-of-vlookups-lookup-column/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Paste these two CSE formulas on the sheet displaying the results.

Dynamic Column Headers:

- `=IFERROR( INDEX($B$1:$I$1,SMALL( IF($B$1:$I$1<>"", IF( COUNTIF($U$5:$U$10, $B$1:$I$1), COLUMN($B$1:$I$1)-COLUMN($B$1)+1)), COLUMN(A$1))),"")`
- Place formula in top left corner of result area.
- Edit the following Values:

  - **`$B$1:$I$1`** is the range of the header row on the raw data sheet.
    *This range can go from the first column header which may be displayed to the last column header which may be displayed and may include column headers in between which will never be chosen for display. If a header is not chosen for display it will not appear in the result's header.*
  - **`$U$5:$U$10`** is the range of the cells containing the column header names to show in the results.
    *This range can be vertical or horizontal. Must be large enough to accommodate the max header labels which may be chosen to include in the results. Only non blank cells of the range are displayed in the results column headers.*
  - **`$B$1`** is the first cell in the raw data, header range.
  - **`A$1`** is a auto increment value. Do Not edit this value.
    *The column letter will increment automatically as the formula is copy dragged across.*
  - All ranges and cell references are absolute with the exception of the auto increment column letter.
  - If a reference is not local to the result sheet, qualify it with the sheet name (tab) of the range being referenced (`RawDataSheet!$B$1:$I$1`).
- After the edits, use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Enter</kbd> to make this an array formula.
- Copy Drag across to the right until the max results column labels can be expanded by the formula.

Results Data:

- `=IFERROR( INDEX($B$2:$I$100,SMALL( IF( $D$2:$D$100<>"", IF( COUNTIF($V$6:$V$8, $D$2:$D$100), ROW($D$2:$D$100)-ROW($D$2)+1)), ROW($A1)),MATCH(AA$16,$B$1:$I$1,0)),"")`
- Place formula in the cell below the first pasted formula.
- Edit the following Values:

  - **`$B$2:$I$100`** is the range of the max raw data not including the header row.
  - **`$D$2:$D$100`** is the range of the server names column in the raw data.
    *Do not include the header row in this range. It should contain the same row numbers used in the max raw data range.*
  - **`$V$6:$V$8`** is the range of the cells containing the server names to include in the results.
    *This range can be vertical or horizontal. Must be large enough to accommodate the max server names which may be chosen to include in the results. Only non blank cells in this range are considered when displaying the results.*
  - **`$D$2`** is the first cell (top left) in the raw data range.
  - **`$A1`** is a auto increment value. Do Not edit this value.
    *The row number will increment automatically as the formula is copy dragged down.*
  - All ranges and cell references are absolute with the exception of the auto increment row number.
  - If a reference is not local to the result sheet, qualify it with the sheet name (tab) of the range being referenced (`ReusltsSelectionTab!$V$6:$V$8`).
- After the edits, use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Enter</kbd> to make this an array formula.
- Copy Drag across to the right the same amount as the above formula was dragged.
- With these freshly *copy dragged* cells still selected (or reselect them all), copy drag the entire selection down until the max resulting rows will be accomodated.